# DPM 2012 Installation Error

Tags: sql-server, scdpm

We have windows server 2012 R2.

Trying to install DPM 2012 R2 with SQL Std 2012 R2 Installed on server.

[image]

Installed all prerequisite on server.
All the SQL services are running.

Here is the Error Log https://1drv.ms/t/s!AunGkJZbsiwbgQJ2UJlNYNiAGnNG

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a new report database in "reporting services configuration manager ":

Regarding "[creating new report DB](http://stackzilla.com/system-center-dpm-2012-r2-install-error-id-812/)"